# How should I unit-test java web applications

Tags: java, unit-testing, web-applications

I have servlet, domain objects, some ORM library. I want to unit test decision-making logic (facades) of java web application.

I do not want to use DB in unit tests. I want to use mock object as little as possible.

What approach should I use? What library/framework solves this problem and quite fine documented?

Comment: JUnit, Mockito, dependency injection.

Comment: Well me personally I do use a database since most web applications are heavily database driven, but I use an in-memory database like H2 or HSQL. But for me that is slightly easier because I use an ORM package (JPA/Hibernate) so I don't have to worry about incompatible SQL statements.

Comment: @JBNizet My main question is how to this dependency injection smart way.

Comment: @Gimby Agreed, in-memory DB might be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **unit** test you need to either mock parts of your system or use the actual DB. Otherwise you just write an integration test that has no mocks and runs your scenarios on a live system.

Several things you can do:

- [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) is cool for **integration** tests, where you actually bootstrap you app, so no mocks here. It's pretty fast and easy to set up if you are following some standard Java EE patterns/technologies
- [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)+some in memory db - I know you said you don't want to use a DB but believe me it sometimes is a good idea to test the actual thing. With DBUnit you can pre-populate it easily and with an in-memory db it will be blazing fast (the already mentioned H2 is nice, at my previous job we were using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)). Not technically for unit tests unless you're testing your DB layer.

For other, typical **unit test**, stuff the usual [JUnit](http://junit.org/), [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito), [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core), Jukito (if you're using guava) are nice additions.

I guess you need to choose either you mock or you use the DB, the behavior has to come from somewhere.

Those would be Java based frameworks. Apart from that there are several Javascript based frameworks which will poke your website but those are also integration test.

@Edit: how I personally would do it is: in-memory DB + dbunit for testing the database layer, mocks for everything else since you should be fairly sure the DB layer is working correctly.

Comment: +some in memory db -- It is a solution. 
So, now I have +2 (smart) votes for using in-memory DB. And 0! votes for writing mockups for database-related stuff (factory, dao).

Very strange. Cause mostly people claim dependency injection to be the answer for "how to actually write test code".

Comment: well you said you don't want to use mocks...? Mocking is good for unit tests and can be a time saver, that's why I mentioned Mockito which does that for you. Technically when you use an in-memory DB it's not a unit test unless you're testing your DB layer. Interfaces and factories are very handy not only for unit tests. BUT as I mentioned using a real DB for small integration test can save your bottom in many cases.

Comment: @DmitryKaigorodov so who are these "most people" you speak of? And how can you be so sure you actually understand the true meaning of their statements?

Answer (score 1):

For Unit test:

JUnit http://junit.org/

For integration test:
 Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: JUnit is complementary to the problem of avoiding using database, not the solution.
Integration test is whole another topic.